# Mongoid : saving the parent model does not save has_one instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

OK, just got:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # devise stuff...
  has_one :card
end

class Card
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
end


irb(main):012:0> user = User.new(email: "test@test.com", password: "testtest",password_confirmation: "testtest")
=> #<User _id: 4f4e1b1494b3023d34000003, _type: nil, email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$yCdmjfgK94VrIec062ZXFuoTuApFFaFsDSOVEutoklcSGc4SQH2MG", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>
irb(main):013:0> user.build_card uuid: "test"
=> #<Card _id: 4f4e1b2094b3023d34000004, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, uuid: "test", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f4e1b1494b3023d34000003')>
irb(main):014:0> user.new_record?
=> true
irb(main):015:0> user.card.new_record?
=> true
irb(main):016:0> user.save
=> true
irb(main):017:0> user.card.new_record?
=> true
irb(main):018:0> User.count
=> 1
irb(main):019:0> Card.count
=> 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I need to use

```
has_one :card, autosave: true
```

Comment: If I didn't use autosave true, how would I save user.card?

Answer (score 0):

Yes  , you need to have autosave: true ( Not sure why this information is missing in their official documentation )